# NLog generates too many archives

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using NLog configured this way:

```cs
var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile")
{
    FileName = Path.Combine(_logDirectory, "myApp.log"),
    Layout = "${date} [${level}] ${message} ${exception}${newline}",
    ArchiveFileName = Path.Combine(_logDirectory, "myApp.{#}.log"),
    ArchiveAboveSize = 100 * 1024, MaxArchiveFiles = 9
};
```

On the [file target syntax documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archival-options) it says that the number of {#} characters in the ArchiveFileName property are used to determine the number of digits. As you can see I've only put one hash character but the result is that I'm getting an archiving that goes way beyond myApp.9.log, it can easily reach past .100.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: When posting on Stack Overflow, please bear in mind that if you make users scroll horizontally to see all the code, it's *much* harder to read. I've reformatted the object initializer so that each property is on a separate line, and now there's no scrolling required at all.

Comment: Is the ArchiveAboveSize set correctly (~100 kilobytes)?

Comment: I'm guessing that you want rolling filenames. Try adding `ArchiveNumbering = NLog.Targets.ArchiveNumberingMode.Rolling`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples

Comment: Thanks  also @JonSkeet for the editing and suggestion!

Comment: Thanks @RolfKristensen that was it, setting the numbering to Rolling solved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want rolling filenames. Try adding `ArchiveNumbering = NLog.Targets.ArchiveNumberingMode.Rolling`.

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples